# E-mailing users through RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, mailchimp

I am at the tail end of building a forum/Q&A community-based application, and I would like to add email notifications.  The app has several different entities, including: threads, questions, projects, photos, etc.  The goal is that a user can "subscribe" to any number of these entities, queuing an e-mail whenever the entity receives new comments or activity.  This functionality is very similar to facebook and forums.

I have looked into ActionMailer (with rake tasks and delayed jobs), MailChimp API (and plugins), and other app mailers ([PostageApp](http://postageapp.com/) and [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/)).

I am leaning against ActionMailer, because of potential issues with memory hogging and server overload.  The app will be running on Heroku, but I'm afraid the servers could be easily overwhelmed sending out potentially hundreds of emails every few minutes.

Another complexity is that there will be different types of subscriptions (instant email notification, daily email notification) based on user preference.

What would be the best way to manage email for functionality like this?  Any tips/ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ActionMailer to send with SendGrid, or Postmark. PostageApp still needs an SMTP server and adds an additional dependency, but it can be nice to have. MailChimp is for newsletters only I believe, so that's probably not much use for you here.

Giving a high level overview here, a few things are important:

1. Keep mailer logic from cluttering controllers.
2. Prevent delaying responses to user requests.
3. Avoid issues with "application overload".
4. Handle event-based and periodic emails.

To address #1, you will want to use an Observer to decide when to send an event-based email. To account for #2 and #3, you can drop in DelayedJob so that emails are sent in the background. You can use SendGrid with ActionMailer on Heroku pretty easily (especially if you drop in Pony). For #4 you should just create a rake task that handles the business logic of deciding who to email and queues the send jobs as DJ tasks like the Observer would.

And just to be clear, DelayedJob will execute jobs in a separate process. In the case of Heroku, you're actually running each DelayedJob worker in a different Dyno, which is an entirely separate stack/environment (quite probably on a different physical server). There won't be any issues with your app getting overloaded this way, unless of course your database can't keep up with adding jobs (in which case you can use Redis as a DJ store instead). You can easily scale horizontally by adding more DJ workers as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SimpleWorker, a cloud-based background processing / worker queue.

It's an add-on for Heroku and is able to scale up and out to handle a set of one-time posts or scheduled emails. (A master job, for example, can be scheduled and then when it comes off schedule to run, it queues up 10s, 100s, 1000s of jobs to run concurrently across a scaled out infrastructure.)

Heroku workers can work fine given they'll run as separate processes but if you have variable load, then you want a service that can scale up and scale down by the jobs -- so you a) don't pay for unused capacity and b) can handle burst traffic and batch output.

(Disclosure: I work for the company.)